# SQL Server table swap

Tags: sql-server

I have a table that is truncated and loaded with data everyday the problem is truncating the table is taking a while and users are noticing this. What I am wondering is, is there a way to have two of the same tables and truncate one then load the new data and then have the users user that new table and just keep switching between the two table.

Comment: There's a lot of super smart and experienced people on here.  If you give more detail into what you're storing, why it's stored, and why you truncate, you'll get much more useful responses.  Also include any language / software / version infromation too.

Comment: Although `TRUNCATE` is fast, it will require a schema modification lock; it will be blocked by concurrent activity and visa versa.  The same applies to `SWITCH`, which can be used as part of a swap design.  The upside with `SWITCH` is that the load can occur separately.

Comment: Maybe you could do that with a Synonym. Let the Users only know the Synonym and switch that from one Table to the other

Comment: Thanks Dan and Turo. I will need to do some more research on theses two options but I am glad to see there are options.

Comment: Can this be offloaded to an overnight task or is it already in an overnight slot and users are noticing it then?

Answer (score 0):

If you're clearing out the old table, as well as populating new you could use the OUTPUT clause. Be mindful of the potential for log growth, consider a loop/batch approach if this may be a problem.

```
DELETE
    OldDatabase.dbo.MyTable
OUTPUT
    DELETED.col1
    , DELETED.col2
    , DELETED.col3
INTO
    NewDatabase.dbo.MyTable
```

Or you can Use BCP  which is a handy alternative to be aware of. Note this is using SQLCMD syntax.

```
:setvar SourceServer OldServer
:setvar SourceDatabase OldDatabase
:setvar DestinationServer NewServer
:setvar DestinationDatabase NewDatabase
:setvar BCPFilePath "C:\"

!!bcp "$(SourceDatabase).dbo.MyTable" FORMAT nul -S "$(SourceServer)" -T -n -q -f "$(BCPFilePath)MyTable.fmt"
!!bcp "SELECT * FROM $(SourceDatabase).dbo.MyTable WHERE col1=x AND col2=y" queryout "$(BCPFilePath)MyTable.dat" -S "$(SourceServer)" -T -q -f "$(BCPFilePath)MyTable.fmt" -> "$(BCPFilePath)MyTable.txt"
!!bcp "$(DestinationDatabase).dbo.MyTable" in $(BCPFilePath)MyTable.dat -S $(DestinationServer) -T -E -q -b 2500 -h "TABLOCK" -f $(BCPFilePath)MyTable.fmt
```